# How to use async-await

Tags: javascript, async-await

I need to run various steps in a function but steps have to be run in a specific order. I tried to implement an `Async` function as follow:

```js
async function test() {
    await setTimeout(function() { console.log('1'); }, 5000);
    await setTimeout(function() { console.log('2'); }, 2000);
    console.log('3');
}
test();
```

The expected results in the console should be 1, 2, 3 but I get 3, 2, 1.
It seems that the `await` parameter is ignored.

**EDIT**
The `setTimeout` function is used in the illustrative example above only to simulate a heavy task. In my project, I will not use it. Indeed, I need to connect to a database then reformat the results before moving to the next steps. Even by including the `async-await`, ***2*** is logged-in before ***1***. In other words, empty lists are passed to my graphic because the `async-await` is not taken into consideration. Here my current code:

```
async function refreshData() {
    myLabel = [];
    myValues = [];
    myJSON = [];
    const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
    let db = new sqlite3.Database(fullPath + '/annex/data.db');

    await new Promise(resolve => {
        db.each('SELECT firstName, age FROM Info;', function(err, row) {
            console.log('1');
            myLabel.push(row.firstName);
            myValues.push(row.age);
            myJSON.push(JSON.stringify(row));
        });
        resolve(myValues);
        resolve(myLabel);
        resolve(myJSON);        
    });

    console.log('2');
    db.close();
    popChart(myLabel, myValues);
    popTable(); 
}
```

Comment: The Problem is, that setTimeout doesn't return a promise, so you can't await it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `wait` function:

```
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function test() {
  console.log('1');
  await wait(5000);
  console.log('2');
  await wait(2000);
  console.log('3');
}
test();
```

Comment: The `setTimeout` was used only to simulate heavy tasks. My goal is to connect to a database, collect the information, reformate the results and finally update a graphic. But all steps have to been done in a specific order. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: You've rewritten your question to an entire different question

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following

```
function wait(time) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}
```

and then you just await this function in your method.

Answer (score 0):

using this:

```
async function test() {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(function() { console.log('1'); resolve(); }, 5000)
    });
    await new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(function() { console.log('2'); resolve(); }, 2000)
    });
    console.log('3');
}  
test();
```

Answer (score 0):

For using `await` on a `function` & waiting till the function executes, it must be running on a `promise`, so you can create a new function `delay` which calls `setTimeout` within itself but runs on `promise`, so it will return once the console is logged after timeout & the calling function will hold the execution until it gets the promise `resolved`

Read [this](https://javascript.info/async-await) for better understanding with more examples

```js
function delay (val,time){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(val); resolve(true) }, time);
  });
}

async function test() {
    await delay('1',5000);
    await delay('2',2000);
    console.log('3');
}

test();
```